# rsync and permission denied

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, rsync

I'm simply trying to copy a tar file from my laptop to my Amazon EC2 instance using `rsync`, but get this error:

```
opening connection using: ssh -l root ec2-54-245-194-3.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
rsync --server -vvve.Lsf . /Downloads
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(605) [sender=3.0.9]
[sender] _exit_cleanup(code=12, file=io.c, line=605): about to call exit(255)
```

This is the command I ran from my laptop as **root**:

```
rsync -az -vvv -e ssh /Downloads/employees_db-full-1.0.6.tar.bz2 root@ec2-54-245-194-
3.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:/Downloads
```

A security keypair was generated on the instance and using it I am able to ssh connect to the instance without any problem.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Used scp instead and specified key pair in the copy command. Finally worked.